# Export a simple DataSet with key-value associations to CSV in Mathematica 10

Tags: export, dataset, csv-format

I'm trying to Export a simple dataset with key-value pairs to a CSV

```
Export["n.csv", MyDataset, "CSV"]
```

This results in a single-line serialization:

```
Dataset[<|"A" -> 3757, "B" -> 426, "C" -> 193, ...."D" -> 1|>, TypeSystem`Assoc[TypeSystem`Atom[String], TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 15], <|"Origin" -> HoldComplete[Sort[Dataset`DatasetHandle[265575026537634], Greater]], "ID" -> 109770792907938|>]
```

The desired result is:

```
A,3757
B,426
C,193
...
D,1
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to make Export do the conversion or for a way to transform your dataset to a form that can be handled by Export? The latter should be easy; something with Normal and then converting the list to a table (various possible approaches).

Comment: Oh, it doesn't suppport datasets:-) I can't seem to find a simple function to do the conversion, any tips?  I just want the desired result (Also shown visually in Mathematica).

Comment: For your simple example this will do: `ExportString[(ds // Normal // Normal) /. Rule -> List, "CSV"]` (Replace `ExportString` with `Export` in your case though.)

Comment: Its worth noting that both simple row and column based datasets now export cleanly to CSV in 10.1 but not 10.0.2.  Complex datasets involving nested Assocations don't throw an error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
ds = Dataset[<|"A" -> 3757, "B" -> 426, "C" -> 193, "D" -> 1|>]
```

[image]

Now, to create the CSV you can use:

```
Export["text.csv", List@@@Normal@Normal@ds]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to accomplish this:

```
Export["text.csv", Transpose@Normal@ds[{Keys, Values}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

As Gordon Coale points out Mathematica 10.1+ supports dataset export as CSV:

```
Export["test.csv", ds, "CSV"]
```

However, I found it to be unstable if there are missing values. Instead I use this script:

```
Export[ "data/test.csv",
  {Normal@Keys[ ds[1] ]} ~ Join ~
    (Normal@Values[ds] /. {Missing["KeyAbsent", _] -> ""}),
  "CSV"
]
```

It produces CSV files that are very similar to Mathematica's export.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new function `TextString` in V10, and one option can be used to format the export of Association.

```
ds=Dataset[<|"A"->3757,"B"->426,"C"->193,"D"->1|>]
Export["test.txt",TextString[ds//Normal,AssociationFormat->{"","\n","",","}]]
Export["test.csv",TextString[ds//Normal,AssociationFormat->{"","\n","",","}],"TextDelimiters"->None]
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the above to work. It put rules into the file and I just wanted values. Assuming that the Datasets holds a list of association objects as a simple table i.e. does not have multiple levels, I used

```
Export["output.csv", ds[Values[#]&]//Normal]]
```

Values is applied to every association object and Normal strips the head and table metadata out. There does not appear to be an operator version of Values.