# Export DataSet as CSV or XLS

Tags: export, dataset

One question:

How can I export a DataSet to CSV and XLS ?

```
Dataset[{<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2|>, <|"A" -> 3, "B" -> 4|>, <|"A" -> 5, 
   "B" -> 6|>}]
```

Comment: Have a look at `ExportString[dataset, "CSV"]`.

Comment: @J.M. I got the following error: `"Dataset of the given form could not be exported as format \
\"\!\(\"CSV\"\)\""`

Comment: Interesting... I can export that particular example in 11.2.

Comment: @J.M. Maybe it is the version of Mathematica... I have 11.0 and I tried it with an even simple example (see question) and I still get the same error.

Comment: You might see if this helps https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56737/export-a-simple-dataset-with-key-value-associations-to-csv-in-mathematica-10 or you can search mathematica.stackexchange for Export Dataset and find a variety of questions and answers

Comment: @Bill Thanks for the link!

Comment: @james 11.1 added much better support for exporting Dataset to CSV, and many improvements to CSV in general. I'd recommend upgrading to a later version if possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
entries = List @@@ Normal@dataset;
keys = dataset[1, Keys] // Normal

csvDataSet = PrependTo[entries, keys];

Export["text.csv", csvDataSet]
```

Comment: Nice ! Works ! :)

Comment: I use a similar defined function frequently:  `assocToLists[assoc_] :=
 Prepend[Values[Normal[assoc]], First[Keys[Normal[assoc]]]];`

Comment: Any idea on how to answer the second part, export to XLS or XLSX?

Answer (score 8):

According to documentation, Export can directly push out a dataset as an CSV. The below statements work fine.

```
ds = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "Lunch" -> "Chicken", 
    "Luncheon Options" -> "", "Lunch Choices" -> ""|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 6, "Lunch" -> "", "Luncheon Options" -> "Beef", 
    "Lunch Choices" -> ""|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "7", "Lunch" -> "", "Luncheon Options" -> "", 
"Lunch Choices" -> "Lamb"|>
   }]
Export["Downloads/Lunch Options.csv", ds]
```