# Export output to a text file

Tags: export, column, coordinate

I have the following output obtained after optimizing the positions of geometry using `Minimize`
command

```
{x[1] -> 1011.07, y[1] -> 1127.56, z[1] -> 420.922, x[2] -> 940.095, 
 y[2] -> 1041.71, z[2] -> 414.793, x[3] -> 754.727, y[3] -> 1088.95, 
 z[3] -> 467.422}
```

I have converted this to input form and saved in another variable,

```
coord = {x[1] -> 1011.07, y[1] -> 1127.56, z[1] -> 420.922, x[2] -> 940.095, 
 y[2] -> 1041.71, z[2] -> 414.793, x[3] -> 754.727, y[3] -> 1088.95, 
 z[3] -> 467.422}
```

I would like to save this output as three columns corresponding to x,y,z coordinates of a geometry in a text file.

I think I should be using the export option, I tried

```
`Export["output.txt", coord]`
```

and this gives

```
x[1] -> 1018.4781995039851
y[1] -> 1136.9092785077921
z[1] -> 422.85069778505175
x[2] -> 949.2538801819732
y[2] -> 1051.3795795311353
z[2] -> 404.52636548576334
x[3] -> 763.3574381125803
y[3] -> 1053.2894203505348
z[3] -> 473.80190652330657
```

I would like to ask for suggestions on how to save this in the following way

```
index  x                    y                   z
1     1018.4781995039851 1136.9092785077921     422.85069778505175
2     949.2538801819732   :
3     763.3574381125803   :
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach that address the core of your request

First strip the values from the `Association` and group them with `Partition`.

```
z1 = Values[coord] // Partition[#, 3] & ;
```

Now create a file variable

```
theFile = File["exportFile.txt"];
```

Export as follows (using "Table" argument to `Export`

```
Export[theFile, z1, "Table"];
```

This file will end up in the directory referred to by `Directory[]`

---x---

Now a little more complication

Add a columns of row indices to the left of your table with (I think it is convoluted syntax, but it works....)

```
z2 = Insert[z1 // Transpose, Range[3], 1] // Transpose;
```

The next picture shows z1 and z2.

[image]
Add a row of labels to the top of your table

```
z3 = Prepend[z2, {"index", "x", "y", "z"}];
```

And then `Export` the variable `z3` instead of `z1` as above.

The only problem is the labels aren't aligned properly; this could be a problem or not; depending on how you will use the exported file.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I could export the data without the index. While trying to evaluate `z2`, I get `Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of <<1>> cannot be transposed.`

Comment: I added a picture to the answer which will hopefully help us get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 4):

If this is really the structure, maybe you could use a dataset instead?

```
pdata = Partition[coord/. h_[i_Integer] -> h, 3]
ds = Dataset[Association @@@ pdata]
```

Indexes are supplied automatically. E.g.,

```
ds[[1]]
```

Comment: Thanks. May I know how to export `ds`?

Comment: See the [answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170828/export-dataset-as-csv-or-xls).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version which I think is showing some useful tricks specific to Mathematica:

```
 data = {
        x[1]->1011.07,y[1]->1127.56,z[1]->420.922, 
        x[2]->940.095,y[2]->1041.71,z[2]->414.793,
        x[3] -> 754.727,y[3]->1088.95,z[3]-> 467.422
 }

 Export[
   FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory,"Desktop","data.txt"}],
   Join[
     {{"index", "x", "y", "z"}},
     Table[{i, x[i], y[i], z[i]}, {i, 3}] /. data
   ],
   "Table"
 ]
```

Some explanations:

- I find it more convenient and less error-prone to work with full path-names when working with files than to rely on the current value of `Directory[]`.
- `FileNameJoin` and the `$*Directory` variables are essential tools to work with filenames that I think every Mathematica user should know about.
- There is nothing wrong with using `File` to specify the filename to export to here, but I think for such relatively simple use cases it is an unnecessary abstraction.
- As you have your data as a list of rules it seems easiest to take advantage of that fact when constructing the tabular data you are after.
- I could have used `Prepend` instead of `Join` which would have saved me the extra pair of curly brackets, but I find it more clear to write the header before the data in such cases...